# How to create a dynamic page(new page) after input new information in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make dynamic pages. this means when I add new information in app they make new page about new information just like weather app in apple. when you add new places you can see the weather if you swipe left or right which widget should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageView ! https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html
It's pretty easy :)